# How to connect to a DB in a Virtual Network in Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-virtual-network

I have a Spring application server running on my local machine, and I want to establish a connection to a MySQL database hosted on a virtual network in Azure. Azure specifies that only resources within the virtual network can access it. How can I achieve this?

I tried watching some YouTube videos for VNets but i understood nothing

Answer (score 0):

The database server should be public accessible, and your public IP should be added to the whitelist.

You can modify this settings in the networking tab at the database server resource.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).